# Some window buttons won’t change to left

Tags: 18.10, gnome-tweak-tool, window-buttons

I use ubuntu 18.10 and since yesterday I have a problem with window buttons.

I’ve set in tweaks to show only close button on the left.
However, right now some applications open with default all three buttons on the right and some with my custom settings.

How can I set all windows to use my custom settings declared in tweaks?

[image: buttonsleftandright]
Some applications that won’t change buttons: file explorer, pantheon-terminal, screenshot, settings.
Some applications that change buttons:
Firefox, signal, vs code.

Comment: are you trying to keep only close button on left and remaining minimize and maximize on right?

Comment: *What* are those applications that are not following your custom settings?

Comment: @PRATAP I want only close button on the left side of window.

Comment: @pomsky file explorer, pantheon-terminal, settings, screenshot. However, firefox, signal, vs code displays properly buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close:appmenu'
```

Comment: I've already tried that, but with no result.